# RSACryptoServiceProvider for License Validation

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

First of all, our product must be available fully offline, which means, I cannot validate the license online (sadly).

I am currently using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt my data. This works perfectly fine and I can also decrypt the data using my private key.

Now I have stumbled across a problem. When I encrypt my data multiple times, I generate different results because of the padding. The problem I have now is, if I want to validate the license without the private key, how is that possible? My approach was to take the same information I have, generate an identical key with the same data and check if the newly generated key matches the entered license key. This is not possible when the generated key always differs.

E.g.: If I encrypt the string `"Test 123"` I (for example) get the license key `ABC123`. On our product I then take the same string (`"Test 123"`) and encrypt it again, using the public key. For now the result is always different and not `ABC123`, but (for example) `B21CA3`, `AC23B1`, `3BAC21`, ..., which would always result in the validity check to fail.

Is there something I completely missed or is it even possible to accomplish my target with the current approach? If this is not possible, what are the common approaches to do this exact use-case?

Comment: try the other way around: instead of encrypting your data, _sign it_. after all: it's not a secret for the user what he's allowed to do. he should only be prevented from doing things he's not allowed to.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for your reply. Just to confirm that I understood it correctly. A simple approach would be when I take a passphrase and sign the content with that? The problem I see with this is, that this can easily be cracked, since I need to store the passphrase somewhere within our product, which would then lead to an easy mechanism to decipher the data and then forge e.g. the validity duration of the license. But maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Passphrase? You sign the license on your end, distribute the signed license to your users, and then your code verifies the license before continuing. No passphrase anywhere.

Comment: no. not a passphrase. _signing_ it, like your encryption, is an asymetric process with a private key (you use to sign) and a public key (your app uses to verify). however, at the point of "attackers inspect and change the source code", all of this is moot, since they can just change the  method `CheckIfSomethingIsAllowed()` to always return true - no matter how elaborate your protection.